# How to parse XML data into below code instead of JSON

Tags: android, xml, json

I am new to Android and Java. Below code parses JSON data from URL and populates into ListView. But I have URL that sends XML data, so I want to Parse XML instead of JSON and populate same in ListView. What changes do i require into this code. Let me know if you require other classes code.

```java
public class RemoteFetchService extends Service {

    private int appWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    private AQuery aquery;
    private String remoteJsonUrl = "http://laaptu.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/widgetlist.key";

    public static ArrayList<ListItem> listItemList;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * Retrieve appwidget id from intent it is needed to update widget later
     * initialize our AQuery class
     */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.hasExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID))
            appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        aquery = new AQuery(getBaseContext());
        fetchDataFromWeb();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    /**
     * method which fetches data(json) from web aquery takes params
     * remoteJsonUrl = from where data to be fetched String.class = return
     * format of data once fetched i.e. in which format the fetched data be
     * returned AjaxCallback = class to notify with data once it is fetched
     */
    private void fetchDataFromWeb() {
        aquery.ajax(remoteJsonUrl, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void callback(String url, String result, AjaxStatus status) {
                processResult(result);
                super.callback(url, result, status);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Json parsing of result and populating ArrayList<ListItem> as per json
     * data retrieved from the string
     */
    private void processResult(String result) {
        Log.i("Resutl", result);
        listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            int length = jsonArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
                listItem.heading = jsonObject.getString("title");
                listItem.content = jsonObject.getString("description");
                listItem.imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("imageUrl");
                listItemList.add(listItem);
            }
            storeListItem();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Instead of using static ArrayList as we have used before,no we rely upon
     * data stored on database so saving the fetched json file content into
     * database and at same time downloading the image from web as well
     */
    private void storeListItem() {
        DatabaseManager dbManager = DatabaseManager.INSTANCE;
        dbManager.init(getBaseContext());
        dbManager.storeListItems(appWidgetId, listItemList);

        int length = listItemList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            ListItem listItem = listItemList.get(i);
            final int index = i;
            aquery.ajax(listItem.imageUrl, Bitmap.class,
                    new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public void callback(String url, Bitmap bitmap,
                                AjaxStatus status) {
                            super.callback(url, bitmap, status);
                            storeBitmap(index, bitmap);
                        };
                    });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saving the downloaded images into file and after all the download of
     * images be complete begin to populate widget as done previously
     */
    private void storeBitmap(int index, Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileManager.INSTANCE.storeBitmap(appWidgetId, bitmap,
                listItemList.get(index).heading, getBaseContext());
        count++;
        Log.i("count",
                String.valueOf(count) + "::"
                        + Integer.toString(listItemList.size()));
        if (count == listItemList.size()) {
            count = 0;
            populateWidget();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Method which sends broadcast to WidgetProvider so that widget is notified
     * to do necessary action and here action == WidgetProvider.DATA_FETCHED
     */
    private void populateWidget() {

        Intent widgetUpdateIntent = new Intent();
        widgetUpdateIntent.setAction(WidgetProvider.DATA_FETCHED);
        widgetUpdateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetId);
        sendBroadcast(widgetUpdateIntent);

        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: this service is parsing json data. you have to read or google for parsing xml data.basically there are 3 types.saxparser, dom and xmlpullparser. read something about this(sax is good in my suggestion) first.

Comment: Yes Ranjit, This is JSON. Can you help me parsing SAX in the same code ? That would be really helpful

Comment: see these video tutorials..you will clear all about this. http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=154

Comment: see all from 154 to 159 for xml parsing with saxparser. see other tutorials to know extra things about android ..  http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6